# Setting checkbox values

Tags: c#

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string str = mas.empdetadd(CheckBox1.Checked.ToString(), CheckBox2.Checked.ToString(), CheckBox3.Checked.ToString(), CheckBox4.Checked.ToString(), txtnom.Text, ddgroup.SelectedItem.Text);

        if (str == "1")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Employee Details  Already Added In this ID ..!!');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Employee Details Added Succesfully..!!');", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I have 4 CheckBoxes. Presently when I click on a checkbox it returns value as "true" and "false". I want to save this true value as "1" and False value as "0" into database. How can I do this. Also, how do I clear the checkbox after button click event

My Class

```
public string empdetadd( string ot, string pf, string esi, string tds)
{
    string qry = "insert into EmpDetails values( + ot + "','" + pf + "','" + esi + "','" + tds + "')";
}
```

Comment: `int i = checkbox.Checked ? 1 : 0;` do with `i` what ever you want

Comment: Please improve your question. It does not show the code where it saves the value into database. Just use `if(CheckBox1.Checked)` rather than converting it to string. `Set Checkbox1.Checked = false` for clearing the checkbox

Comment: Ot,pf,esi and tds are checkbox1,checkbox2,checkbox3 and checkbox4.I dont know how to convert its value into 1 and 0.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to store it in the database as a boolean?

Comment: @Sayse I want save values are 1 and 0 for set pf and Ot.If pf is 1 employee is eligible for pf or he is not.

Comment: `pf` and `Ot` mean nothing to me, but it is alot clearer and less error prone to say if `pf` is `True`, employee is eligible

Comment: @Reniuz Sir,How does it works?How should I pass values.

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee Maku sure the Aurguments in empdetadd.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
string str = mas.empdetadd(Convert.ToInt32(CheckBox1.Checked),Convert.ToInt32(CheckBox2.Checked), Convert.ToInt32(CheckBox3.Checked), Convert.ToInt32(CheckBox4.Checked),txtnom.Text, ddgroup.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee Always Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to store the values as 1 or 0. Just use the parametrized query and set the parameter value of Boolean Type i.e. 'True' or 'False'. Keep your database column also of Boolean type and let the database stores it the way it likes.

To uncheck all the checkboxes on a form you can use this code.

```
foreach (void Control_loopVariable in this.Controls) {
    Control = Control_loopVariable;
    if ((Control) is CheckBox) {
        ((CheckBox)Control).Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir,I want to save value as 1 or 0 then only I can work properly if value is 1 employee is eligible for PF and value is 0 he is not eligible for pf.

Comment: If your column can have only two values then its better to store it as Boolean. Assume 1 to be True and 0 to be false then implement the logic whatever you want. Still if you want 1 or 0 then use the reply in first comment to your question by Reniuz.